# Grpc throws Specified method is not supported

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-net

I am trying to call grpc server that implements code first service. I am unable to call that service from client if I add **CallOptions** to the service method parameters for **passing bearer token**.

When I execute the client it throws the following exception:

> Unhandled exception. System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
> at ProtoBuf.Grpc.Internal.Proxies.ClientBase.ICustomerService_Proxy_0.ICustomerService.CreateCustomer(CreateCustomerCommand , CallOptions )

*If I remove the CallOptions parameter and then execute the call it works perfectly as it should.*

Additionally, Grpc.Core.Api package referenced in client and server have the same version.

***Service Implementation***

```
    [Authorize]
    public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
    {
        IMediator _mediator;
        public CustomerService(IMediator mediator)
        {
            _mediator = mediator;
        }

        public Task CreateCustomer(CreateCustomerCommand request, CallOptions callOptions)
        {
            return _mediator.Send(request);
        }
    }
```

Can someone please tell me if I am missing anything or if I can pass token in my grpc request in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Marc Gravell for the support. I have copied the solution here:

short version: use CallContext, not CallOptions; CallContext has a .CallOptions, or many of the expected features are directly available (for example, .RequestHeaders, .CancellationToken, etc)

longer version: protobuf-net.Grpc, being code-first, attempts to unify the client and server APIs so that the same interface (presumably ICustomerService in this case) makes sense for both the client and server side. This is not possible with CallOptions (client) vs ServerCallContext (server), so protobuf-net.Grpc creates CallContext which bridges the gap between both